# Bootstrap keep first tab of accordion to be opened all time

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have accordion with four tabs. I want to prevent the first tab from collapsing. If any other tab is clicked, all other tabs must work with the default toggle collapse behaviour except the first tab. I want the first tab to be unable to be toggled and always to be opened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8ggkvwd9/2/)

You just need to change to first accordion element as follows -

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a role="button" data-parent="#accordion" href="javascript:void(0)" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```